# Problems translating text with gettext

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Some string in the theme I'm using are not translated and I'm using gettext on the function.php but It's not working.

This is the code I'm using:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'custom_strings_translation', 20, 3);

function custom_strings_translation( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
  switch ( $translated_text ) {
case 'View Cart' : 
    $translated_text =  __( 'Ver Carrito', '__x__' );
    break;
case "You currently have no items in your cart." : 
    $translated_text =  __( 'No tienes artículos en el carrito.', '__x__' );
    break;
case 'Shopping Cart' : 
    $translated_text =  __( 'Carrito', '__x__' );
    break;
case 'Previous' : 
    $translated_text =  __( 'Anterior', '__x__' );
    break;
case 'Next' : 
    $translated_text =  __( 'Siguiente', '__x__' );
    break;
  }

  return $translated_text;
}
```

Why it's not working and what should I do? Thanks

PS My site is: https://brisaperu.com/

Comment: One other minor thing, the text-to-translate should have a leading single underscore `_(...)` and not a double underscore `__(...)`.  Various other causes can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/FAQ.html#integrating_noop)

Comment: thanks, still can't do it, but I will keep trying